# What is the best way to set ports in PM2?

Tags: nginx, ports, pm2

I'm unsure of the best way to set ports in PM2. I don't see this documented anywhere. I'm using a front-facing nginx server which listens on proxys to specific ports on the backend that represent the node servers. How do I best set this type of configuration up?

Answer (score 1):

One method is with `env` in `process.json`

```
{
        "name"       : "MyApp",
        "script"     : "./MyApp/app.js",
        "instances"  : "1",
        "exec_mode"  : "cluster_mode",
        "env": {"PORT": 3030}
}
```